# How to define $H^k(\Omega)$ given this definition of $H^k(T^n)?$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $T^n$ be the $n$-torus, and define
$$H^s(T^n):=L^2_s(\mathbb{Z}^n),$$
where given $\xi \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $\mu_s(\{\xi\}):=(1+|\xi|^2)^s$.

This is essentially the definition given in [Warner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387908943).  However, it is not clear to me how one would go on to define $H^s(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, from this. My quesion is exactly this: how do we do this? Are there references?

Comment: What does $L^2_s$ mean?  A weighted space of square-summable sequences?  So this definition of $H^s(T^n)$ isn't even a space of functions on $T^n$??  What's wrong with e.g. taking $H^k(\Omega)$ to be the closure of square intgbl smooth functions supported in $\Omega$ with square intgbl derivatives?

Comment: @mathematician Yes, it is a weighted space of square-summable sequences.Yes, this isn't a space of function on $T^n$, the idea of this definition is to look at the Fourier coefficients instead of the functions.

The problem is that Warner gives this definition in order to present a self-contained exposition and proof of some regularity theorems/lemmas etc for Hodge theory. I don't think that there is anything "wrong", I just want to understand how this definition works out.

Comment: I guess you require $\Omega$ bounded. Then $\Omega$ is inside some big square in $\mathbb R^n$, so you think of $\Omega \subset T^n$.

Comment: @JohnMa But how would I define $H^s(\Omega)$ for $\Omega \subset T^n$?

Comment: In this context it seems that you need only the space $H^s_0(\Omega)$, which is the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ under the $\|\cdot\|_{H^s}$ norm (think of $\Omega \subset T^n$ so $C^\infty_0(\Omega) \subset C^\infty (T^n)$) @AloizioMacedo

Comment: @JohnMa So you take $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$, see what is the image by the "Fourier coefficient" operator, and take its closure?

Comment: Yes @AloizioMacedo